# how do I check for button press in python flask and EJS? Is it possible?

Tags: python, flask, ejs

i am trying to make a program that checks every time a specific button is pressed, this would be done with python, i am thinking of using flask however i am not sure how to do it as the website is in EJS. please help and give suggestions on how to do it and if possible code snippets.

I can't find any docs on this, so please help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing something serverside when the button is clicked? (i.e. a regular HTTP POST operation - search for "flask http post" in that case) - or are you planning to handle it in-browser with Javascript? In that case - search for event listener / onclick.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh , this would be done in python, I don’t know if I should use flask or not, what I want to do is make an on-Button-press app so on a button press in an ejs Website it says some info in the chat. I have tried using post with flask and Eis but it doesn’t work